# Is it better to use There are or Where are?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, difference

In this sentence is it better to use **there** are or **where** are?
*There/Where are more gamers, so it's market for the....*

Comment: Hi Dan! I don't think there's enough context in your sentence fragment to answer your question. Ordinarily, especially if used at the beginning of a sentence, "where" is a question word - you're asking about the location of gamers. **There** and **where** can't be used as substitutes for one another, so it's hard to get a sense of what you're trying to say. "There" seems the likelier choice, from the sentence fragment we've seen so far. "So it's market for that" is not grammatical English: you need an article ("a", or more likely "the") to go before "market". Good luck!

Comment: Ok, so where is used for location, and what does There exactly mean?

Comment: **Where** is not *only* used for location; it has several other uses. and **there** is *also* often used for location (and also has several other uses). It depends on how it's being used. Your sentence fragment appears to use the definition 3 of the adverb from [this entry for the word](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/there), that starts with "(usually **there is/are**)".

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help!

Comment: If you use **there** you are stating a fact. If you use **where** you are asking a question. When writing the sentence, is the location of the gamers known? Are you pointing at them, or is the room empty?